# Average per thousand calculations in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to calculate the average per thousand and can't seem to get the formula right! I am new to Power bi so any help would he appreciated:

Sample data is below:

[image]

appointment data, broken down to an average per 1000 for the NC category

*I have tried adding a new column and writing a new measure but can't seem to get the right result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this **Calculated Table**

```
Result Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Sample data',
    'Sample data'[N C],
    "Average", AVERAGE('Sample data'[APPOINTMENTS])
)
```

Comment: thanks @peter for that. Can I then break it down to average per NC category per 1000 appointments?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what number an "average per 1000" should be (as opposed to a "moving average"), but I'm sure we wouldn't have this discussion if copyable sample data had been provided.